# Comparing two source codes without repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository

Say I have two local folders containing two different versions of a small webapp. The differences are minute - maybe two files have differences by a couple of lines. Neither are located on any repository. Is there a tool for viewing the differences between the two projects? I know visual studio has tools for this, but I believe it's only for viewing code in a repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a diff tool like [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) or [K3Diff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) which does folder comparison. You don't need source control to diff two folders.